# Highchart setextreme plots 1 day less in different timezone

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart plotted using Highchart as shown in below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/48e0mngq/1/

Now In above fiddle, I have two text boxes which accepts from and to date in (yyyy/mm/dd) format. And when user click on the "Set" button, X-Axis extreme should set accordingly. This is how I set the extremes:

```
$('#set').click(function(){
    var start = Date.parse($('#startDate').val());
  var end = Date.parse($('#endDate').val());
  console.log(start);
  console.log(end);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(start, end);
});
```

But its behavior differs on different timezones.

For example, my timezone in "India Standard Time" in this time zone it plots one day less than date selected and in EST timezone it works fine.

Is there any workaround to get rid of this?

Comment: Have you tried using `time.timezone` property?: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone

Comment: @KamilKulig : It would be nice if you can give me example of it ?

Comment: API link from my previous comment contains the demo - you'll find it in "Try it" section.